Is the subgroup of $R$-trivial classes of an algebraic group an algebraic subgroup?
Let $G$ be an algebraic group over a field $F$. I'm willing to assume it is linear if that changes anything to what I'm going to say, and even reductive if that helps (but I don't think it should make a difference).
Manin defined for any extension $K/F$ the subgroup $RG(K)$ of $R$-trivial classes in $G(K)$ (and the group of $R$-equivalence classes is the quotient group $G(K)/RG(K)$). This has notably been studied by Merkurjev which gave a very good account of this group of equivalence classes for adjoint semisimple groups, and is a standard tool to prove that a given group is not (stably) rational as a variety.
Now this subgroup $RG(K)\subset G(K)$ is functorial in $K$, which leads me to this natural question, which does not seem to be addressed in those articles: do the $RG(K)$ arise from an actual algebraic subgroup $RG\subset G$?

Over an algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$, every connected affine algebraic group is rational, so $RG(\bar K) = G(\bar K)$. But this equality does not hold over an arbitrary field, which is exactly the point. So $RG$ is not even an étale sheaf in general, let alone representable by a scheme.

I see, indeed, embarrassing that I did not think of that. Thank you for answering!

Where does Manin's definition appear?

@LSpice typing "Manin R-equivalence" into my favourite search engine gives for instance this paper of Chernousov and Merkurjev that contains the definition (and many papers that don't but at least cite Manin's book on cubic forms).
